# Opencart 3 getProduct method causes slow page loading

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

My Opencart 3.0 is running very slow. In the network tab in the chrome browser inspector, it records 23.02 seconds for the category page to load.

When I try to debug it, I could see that the slow loading happens here

```
catalog/model/catalog/product.php - public function getProduct($product_id)
```

Inside this method, when I comment out this line in the returned array - `'product_id' => $query->row['product_id']`, the loading speed comes to 7s.

The method `getProduct($product_id)` is called in this method `getProducts($data = array())`. The part where the method is called looks like below.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
   $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
}
```

When I comment out this line

```
//$product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
```

The loading speed goes to 3.5s.

What I could not figure out is why this part of the code takes time to return - `'product_id' => $query->row['product_id']`

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issues comes from `getProduct()` and `getProducts()` methods in the `catalog/model/catalog/product.ph`p file. Especially this row:

`'product_id' => $query->row['product_id']`

So you could check your DB performance, how much time is taking to complete this query.

1. If it takes too much time and your columns are not indexed, you could [index](https://www.codecademy.com/article/sql-indexes) them.

2. You could also try to limit the number of rows being retrieved in the query by using a LIMIT clause or a WHERE clause.
3. You could use Opencart cache system, to reduce time.

On first sign it looks more like DB related problem, instead of code problem.